# Access subsequent word with capitals

Tags: python, regex

I use below regex to match the subsequent word after word I'm searching for, in this case the word I'm searching for is `test` :

```
import re

chs = "this is a test Ab Here here big"

print(re.compile(r'test \w+').search(chs).group().split()[1])
```

From above `Ab` is printed. How can I modify to return all subsequent words that have capital letter subsequent to word `test` ?

Update :

So in this case 'Ab Here' is returned.

Comment: You can simplify the current code to `re.search(r'test (\w+)', chs).group(1)`. What have you tried to solve your new problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get consecutive capitalized words using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525993/get-consecutive-capitalized-words-using-regex)

Comment: @thepen What is your expected output ?

Comment: @Rakesh please see question update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test\s([A-Z].+?)\s[a-z]`

matches `Ab Here` in `this is a test Ab Here here big`

See: https://regex101.com/r/jYZucl/1

Answer (score 1):

A non `regex` solution would be easier:

```
chs = "This is A test Ab Here here Big"

index = chs.index('test')
get_all_captial = [val for val in chs[index:].split() if val[0].isupper()]
print(get_all_captial)

# ['Ab', 'Here', 'Big']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chs = "This is a Test Ab Here here big"
get_all_captial = [val for val in chs.split() if val[0].isupper()]
>>>get_all_captial
['This', 'Test', 'Ab', 'Here']
```