# R Regex to identify 2 or 3 consecutive capitalized words in string [R]

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to replicate this answer using R regex and limiting to only 2/3 consecutive capitalizations and accounting for words entirely capitalized: [Get consecutive capitalized words using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525993/get-consecutive-capitalized-words-using-regex)

The idea is to pull names from other jumbled word garbage:

```
    test_string <- "we need a test for Andrew Smith or other names like Samuel L Jackson, but we Don't Want Weird Instances Where more stuff is capitalized, but we do want where the entire name is capitalized, like DEREK JETER or MIKE NELSON TROUT"

    desired_extract
    [1] Andrew Smith
    [2] Samuel L Jackson
    [3] DEREK JETER
    [4] MIKE NELSON TROUT
```

Comment: Why not use NER to extract names?

Comment: what should happen to this part of the sentence you have up in your post? `Don't Want Weird Instances Where`?

Comment: That should be deleted since it is longer than 2 or 3 in a row capitalized

Comment: Agree with @Sonny NER will give better results probably.

Comment: Here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56710413/3832970) that will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is to use the {1,2} operator instead of + to limit amount of repetitions.

```
([A-Z]+[a-z]*(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z]+[a-z]*){1,2})
```

Edit: Edited so it also works on all caps words.

Comment: This returns: `"Andrew Smith" "Samuel L Jackson" "Want Weird Instances" "DEREK JETER" "MIKE NELSON TROUT" ` which does not meet all of the steps required.

Answer (score 2):

What makes this a bit difficult is that you can't nest a forward lookahead operator inside of a clause followed by `{2,3}`. Unfortunately, the best I can do is put this together longhand.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(test_string,"(?<!([A-Z][^ ]{0,20} ))([A-Z][^ ,.]*)[ ,.]([A-Z][^ ,.]*)([ ,.]([A-Z][^ ,.]*))?(?=([ ,.]|$))(?!( [A-Z]))")
```

Results:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Andrew Smith"      "Samuel L Jackson"  "DEREK JETER"       "MIKE NELSON TROUT"
```

This used negative lookbehind, forward lookahead, and negative forward lookahead to identify whether the words are followed by other capitals. Explanation is below and is partially spread out for legibility.

```
# Negative lookback to make sure there wasn't a word starting with a capital and having up to 20 
# characters before the first word in our sequence.
# Note: Lookbehind requires a bounded possibility set such as {,} and won't work with * or +
(?<!([A-Z][^ ]{0,20} )
# A word starting with a capital, followed by 0 or more characters that aren't a space, period, 
# or comma.
([A-Z][^ ,.]*)
# A space a period or a comma.
[ ,.]
# A word starting with a capital, followed by 0 or more characters that aren't a space, period, or 
# comma.
([A-Z][^ ,.]*)
# Maybe a third word indicated by a space/period/comma followed by a word starting with a 
# capital...
([ ,.]([A-Z][^ ,.]*))?
# Forward lookahead to make sure the last character in the capture is followed by a space, comma, 
# period, or end of line character. (Don't cut words in half)
(?=([ ,.]|$))
# Negative forward lookahead to make sure there isn't another word starting with a capital after 
# our word sequence.
(?!( [A-Z]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a PCRE regex with a base R `regmatches`/`gregexpr` using the [SKIP-FAIL technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to match and skip chunks of 4 or more capitalized words and only keeping the 1 to 3 capitalized word chunks:

```
(*UCP)\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*){3,}\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*){1,2}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LaOlWr/2)

**Details**

- `(*UCP)` - PCRE verb that makes `\b`, `\s` Unicode aware
- `\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*){3,}\b` - a word boundary (`\b`), an uppercase letter followed with 0+ lowercase ones (`\p{Lu}\p{L}*`, a "capitalized word"), then 3 or more repetitions of 1+ whitespaces (`\s+`) followed with a capitalized word
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - if the match is found with this alternative, discard it and go on to look for another match
- `|` - or
- `\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*){1,2}\b` - 2 or 3 whitespace separated capitalized words within word boundaries.

See [R demo online](https://ideone.com/NPBI3M):

```
test_string <- "we need a test for Andrew Smith or other names like Samuel L Jackson, but we Don't Want Weird Instances Where more stuff is capitalized, but we do want where the entire name is capitalized, like DEREK JETER or MIKE NELSON TROUT"
block <- "\\b\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*(?:\\s+\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*)"
regex <- paste0("(*UCP)", block, "{3,}\\b(*SKIP)(*F)|", block, "{1,2}\\b")
##regex <- "(*UCP)\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*){3,}\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\p{Lu}\p{L}*(?:\s+\p{Lu}\p{L}*){1,2}\b"
regmatches(test_string, gregexpr(regex, test_string, perl=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Andrew Smith"      "Samuel L Jackson"  "DEREK JETER"      
[4] "MIKE NELSON TROUT"
```